# Angular: How can I change the value of a property of a component inside an ngFor

Tags: angular, boolean, click, ngfor, ng-class

Inside an ngFor I have a tabs component. To add a CSS class I use the property `show`  which is a boolean `false`. If I click the component the `show` property toggles to `true`. If I click a second component I need to set `false` previous clicked component.

How can I access and set `false` the `show` property of the sibling components?

```
export class TabComponent implements OnInit {
  show: Boolean = false;

  toggle(event: any) {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }
}

<ng-container *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
  <app-tab [ngClass]="show ? 'open':'closed'"  (click)="toggle($event)"></app-tab>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: You should use `Boolean` with small B instead. And to possibly fix your error, instead of `ngClass` use `class.show`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `Input()` to control state in each tab.

```
export class TabComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  show: boolean = false;

  toggle(event: any) {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }
}

<ng-container *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
  <app-tab
    [show]="tab.show" // or any value you need here
    [ngClass]="tab.show ? 'open':'closed'"  
    (click)="toggle($event)">. 
  </app-tab>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the index value delivered by the `*ngFor`, store the tab shown index and use it in the `ngClass` condition like this :

```
export class TabComponent implements OnInit {
  tabShownIndex = null;

  toggle(index: number) {
    this.tabShownIndex = index;
  }
}

<ng-container *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index;">
  <app-tab [ngClass]="index === tabShownIndex ? 'open':'closed'"  (click)="toggle(index)"></app-tab>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write inside element)

```
<mat-button-toggle-group [formControl]="documentTypeControl">
  <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let d of getDictionaryByName('DOCUMENT_TYPE')"
  [value]="d.text">{{d.text}}</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```